# Removing Thousand Separator PHP

Tags: woocommerce, product, feed

I am trying to format a number in a products feed removing the thousand separator, i used this code:

```
$attributes['Price'] = number_format( $attributes['Price'], 2, '.', ',');
```

but for a source price of 1.399,00 what i get in the feed is

```
<Price>1,40</Price>
```

I am little lost, any help please?

FULL CODE

```
function alter_feed_price_item_remove_thousand_seperator( $attributes, 
$feed_id, $product_id ) {
global $product;
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

// show price without thousand separator
  $attributes['price'] = number_format( $attributes['price'], 2, ',', '') . " EUR";
  // price will look like 1234,57

// IMPORTANT! Always return the $attributes
return $attributes;} 
add_filter( 'wppfm_feed_item_value', 'alter_feed_price_item_remove_thousand_seperator', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function alter_feed_price_item_remove_thousand_seperator( $attributes, $feed_id, $product_id) {
global $product;
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

if ($attributes['Sale_Price'] >= 1 && $attributes['Sale_Price'] < 2) { 
$attributes['Sale_Price'] = sprintf(($attributes['Sale_Price'])*1000). ",00";
} 
if ($attributes['Sale_Price'] >= 2 && $attributes['Sale_Price'] < 3) { 
$attributes['Sale_Price'] = sprintf(($attributes['Sale_Price'])*1000). ",00";
}

if ($attributes['Price'] > 1 && $attributes['Price'] < 2) { 
$attributes['Price'] = sprintf(($attributes['Price'])*1000). ",00";
} 
if ($attributes['Price'] > 2 && $attributes['Price'] < 3) { 
$attributes['Price'] = sprintf(($attributes['Price'])*1000). ",00";
}

return $attributes;
}
add_filter( 'wppfm_feed_item_value', 'alter_feed_price_item_remove_thousand_seperator', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$attributes['Price'] = (double)str_replace(',', '', $attributes['Price']);
```

Comment: TY for the answer but no difference, same result 1,40... :-(

Comment: I think the problem is not on that string of code but on the rest not written here...

Comment: Full Code    `code` function alter_feed_price_item_remove_thousand_seperator( $attributes, $feed_id, $product_id ) {
 global $product;
 $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
 
 // show price without thousand separator
  $attributes['price'] = number_format( $attributes['price'], 2, ',', '') . " EUR";
  // price will look like 1234,57

 // IMPORTANT! Always return the $attributes
 return $attributes;
}
add_filter( 'wppfm_feed_item_value', 'alter_feed_price_item_remove_thousand_seperator', 10, 3 ); `code`